# Intel 8260 bluetooth adapter not found

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Gigabyte Z170N Gaming 5 motherboard running Ubuntu 16.04.2 with built-in wifi and bluetooth. The wifi works fine but the bluetooth does not work at all. The network controller is Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a). More information about the system is show below:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c02 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge]
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge]
04:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge]
04:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge]
04:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge]
07:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6540 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
0b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

and

```
$ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-03-04 16:32:23 EST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1210 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1210 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 04 16:32:23 linux systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 04 16:32:23 linux bluetoothd[1210]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Mar 04 16:32:23 linux bluetoothd[1210]: Starting SDP server
Mar 04 16:32:23 linux systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 04 16:32:23 linux bluetoothd[1210]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13 initialized
```

and

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:0161 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    1.672115] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    1.672127] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.672129] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.672130] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.672133] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.675852] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    1.675852] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    1.675853] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    1.675853] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    1.675853] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    1.675854] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    1.675867] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    1.675873] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    1.675873] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    1.675873] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.988155] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.988156] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.988158] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

See the following links for more information about the motherboard and wireless adapter:

- [Gigabyte GA-Z170N-Gaming 5](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170N-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-manual)
- [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-8260-brief.html)

The wifi and bluetooth components on the motherboard have the following model numbers:

- WFM: E4A471F44FE8
- BDM: E4A471F44FEC

It appears that the bluetooth service is running in Ubuntu but the adapter is not found according to the System Settings. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the bluetooth adapter on this motherboard? If I can't get the bluetooth on the motherboard to work, are there any USB bluetooth adapters that are verified to work with Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of: `lsusb` and also: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @chili555 Revised my question based on your comment.

Comment: Check if BT is enabled in your BIOS. It is most likely disabled there.

Comment: @Pilot6 I looked in the BIOS and couldn't find any settings for bluetooth.

Comment: If you open the case, can you locate the wifi card on the motherboard?  Intel chips will have a WFM and BDM MAC address on wifi cards with bluetooth

Comment: @Jeremy31 According to the manual, the wifi module is called M2_WIFI which I assume has the bluetooth too. You can find the manual for the motherboard at http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170N-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-manual

Comment: @Jeremy31Also, here is more information about the Intel dual band wireless adapter on the motherboard http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-8260-brief.html

Comment: I would expect the bluetooth to show in your `lsusb` results and it doesn't as it would have an ID starting with 8086 or 8087 if I remember correctly

Comment: @Jeremy31 Is there an Intel setting in the BIOS that I need to enable? Or a switch or jumper on the motherboard that I need to turn on?

Comment: @Jeremy31 The model numbers for the wifi and bluetooth on the motherboard are WFM = E4A471F44FE8 and BDM = E4A471F44FEC

Comment: It must be a motherboard or BIOS issue as I find a few different bluetooth issues search for the motherboard model

Comment: @Jeremy31 So are there any solutions to my bluetooth problem?

Comment: A GBU521 IoGear should work fine

Comment: I am running Ubuntu with this device on my Dell Precision 5250. I have an obsolete v 1.2 package for it named "bt-intel8260-firmware". But I'm just being cautious and haven't deleted it yet. But, according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1476900 , "Both Intel 8260 Wifi and Bluetooth firmwares are now available in mainline linux-firmware and has been tested. [...]."

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu is not compatible with BT on this device - I have read it in another forum - hope this helps.

Comment: can you please post some source of information on your statement? i.e. the forum link or some official statement.